# MYSQL QUERY ORDER BY and php styling

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM buy ORDER BY date ASC") or die(mysqli_error());
```

This gives me something like this:

```
Date (d-m-y)       Name    Price
==================================
01/02/2017         xy      $1
22/12/2017         xy      $1
11/05/2017         xy      $1
21/09/2019         xy      $1
```

I want to group them into months/years. I need something like this:

```
Date (d-m-y)           Name    Price
    ==================================

******2017******
/FEBRUARY/

    01/02/2017         xy      $1

/MAY/
    11/05/2017         xy      $1

/DECEMBER/

    22/12/2017         xy      $1

******2019******
/SEPTEMBER/
    21/09/2019         xy      $1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Transform your data in multidimensional array as each year will have array collection of months and each month of year will have their records then print it in your desired format

Answer (score 1):

You can get Month and Year and do Order by First Year and then Month which will give you result as you required.

> SELECT MONTH(`datefield`) as month, YEAR(`datefield`) as year FROM `buy` ORDER BY YEAR,MONTH ASC

Comment: `ORDER BY date` will always first order by year then month then date. SO why to do it separately?

Comment: Yes you are right but its not working for him. That's why given an alternate solution.

Comment: No the issue is not about query, OP needs the way in PHP to format output he has given in question

Answer (score 0):

As you loop through the results you check year and month for changes.
If it changed, add a header.

```
$year="";
$month="";
while (...) {
    $newYear = (...);
    $newMonth = (...);
    if ($year != $newYear) echo $newYear;
    if ($month != $newMonth ) echo $newMonth ;
}
```

Comment: This must be as comment. As it is suggestion

Comment: There is no suggestion, this is a php question.

Comment: You have edited you answer. I have add comment before it